# JsonPatchDocument instantiate nested object if null

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, json-patch

I have a data model like this:

```
Student
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Address address {get; set;}
}    
  
Address 
{
    public string City {get; set;}
    public int Postcode {get; set;}
}
```

And I have the following data:

```
Student1 
{
   "name": "John",
   "address": null
}
```

I want to patch the object with the following command

```
 {
    "value": "Sydney",
    "path": "student/address/city",
    "op": "add"
  }
```

Is it possible to initialize the Address object if it is null (when apply change to this target  "student/address/city"), without having to set it manually ?

I am using

```
 jsonPatchDoc.ApplyTo(student1);
```

Comment: Before that you can read the official example, maybe it can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks I already have a look at the link. It basically says that this will throw an exception in this case (the target does not exist)                                                                        
"If path points to a nonexistent location:
If the resource to patch is a dynamic object: adds a property.
If the resource to patch is a static object: the request fails."

Answer (score 1):

`add` is the wrong instruction here. You want `replace`.

In this JSON

```json
{
   "name": "John",
   "address": null
}
```

The field `address` *exists*, even though its value is null. Because of this, you have to replace that `null` value with an `address` that contains the city. This is the instruction you should provide:

```json
[{
  "op": "replace",
  "path": "/address",
  "value": {
   "city": "Sydney"
  }
}]
```

This results in the resource looking like

```json
{
   "name": "John",
   "address": {
     "city": "Sydney"
   }
}
```

This is compatible with .NET's `JsonPatchDocument`.